# Cannot drag over all body in jquery ui

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui-draggable

My problem has been started when i want to drag a big size elements, i cannot drag those items over all body, i am using bootstrap 3.3.7 and JQueryUI 
here's an example of my problem:
[image]

this is only happens for the big size elements,

> here's an example of code:

```
$('body .removable').draggable({
        cursor: 'move',
        helper: 'clone',
        appendTo: 'body',
        containment: 'window',
        //revert: true,
        //stack: "#fields-drop-area",
        zIndex: 101,
        drag: function (event, ui) {
            $("#trash").removeClass("hidden");
            $(ui.helper).css({ 'width': "12%", "height": "40px",'overflow':'hidden' });
        },
        stop: function (event, ui) {
            $("#trash").addClass("hidden");
            $(ui.helper).css('width', "18%");
        }
    });
```

> the trash droppable code:

```
    $('body #trash').droppable({
    accept: '.removable,.btn-removable',
    hoverClass: 'over-area',
    forceHelperSize: true,
    drop: function (event, ui) {
        debugger;
        document.getElementById('recycle').play();
        var id;
        if (ui.helper.hasClass("dropped-tab")) {
            id = ui.helper.data("id");
            if (ui.helper.hasClass("tab-parent")) {
                $(ui.helper).hide('explode', null, 500, function () { $(ui.draggable.closest('.panel')).remove(); });
                updateTabForm(null, objState.Deleted, id);
            } else if (ui.helper.hasClass("tab-sub")) {
                updateTabForm(id, objState.Deleted, null);
                $(ui.helper).hide('explode', null, 500, function () { ui.draggable.remove(); });
            }
        } else if (ui.helper.hasClass("dropped-field")) {
            id = ui.helper.find('div.panel-heading>label').data('fieldid');
            updateFieldForm(id, objState.Deleted, ui);
            $(ui.helper).hide('explode', null, 500, function () { ui.draggable.remove(); });
        }
        if (ui.draggable.hasClass('btn-success')) {
            $('#fields-drop-area').html('');
        }
    }
});
```

> here's the css:

```
.full-height-page, .full-height-page body {
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    /* this is necessary */
}

body {
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

    @media (min-width: 768px) {
        .grid-divider {
            position: relative;
            padding: 0;
        }

            .grid-divider > [class*='col-'] {
                position: static;
            }

                .grid-divider > [class*='col-']:nth-child(n+2):before {
                    content: "";
                    border-left: 1px solid #DDD;
                    position: absolute;
                    top: 0;
                    bottom: 0;
                }

        .col-padding {
            padding: 0 15px;

    .ui-state-highlight {
        height: 1.5em;
        line-height: 1.2em;
    }

    .body-content #trash {
        width: 20%;
        height: 30%;
        background-color: #f9f9f9;
        content: "sssss";
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 100;
        bottom: 0;
        right: 2%;
        text-align: center;
        border-radius: 8px;
        border: 3px solid #bbf3bf;
    }
```

> here's my Html code:

```
<div class="row grid-divider">
    <div id="trash" class="hidden">
        <h2>Through Items Here</h2>
        <i class="fa fa-5x fa-trash-o  faa-bounce animated"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4" id="tools-container">
        <h4 class="container-title text-center">
            <strong>Toolbox</strong>
        </h4>
        <hr/>
        <div id="tools-container-body" class="height-600"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4" id="tabs-container">
        <h4 class="container-title text-center">
            <strong>Tabs</strong>
        </h4>
        <hr/>
        <div class="height-600" id="tabs-drop-area"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4" id="fields-container">
        <h4 class="container-title text-center">
            <strong>Fields</strong>
        </h4>
        <hr/>
        <div class="height-600" id="fields-drop-area"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

after i remove the containment it works, but i cannot drop into trash

Comment: Please add your CSS, HTML code

Comment: @Liamm12 i added the css , please check.

Answer (score 0):

Without your HTML, I can only guess that the issue has to do with your use of:

```
containment: 'window',
```

Change that to:

```
containment: 'body',
```

and you should be able to drag over the entire page. You can also try removing the "containment" option since it is not needed if you want to be able to drag over the entire screen.

You also need to add the jquery-ui droppable to handle the dropping into trash. I don't see the code in what you provided so try this:

```
$('#trash').droppable({
  over: function (event, ui) {
    //do nothing        
    },
 drop: function (event, ui) {
    console.log("item dropped, handle it");
    }
})
```

Comment: i removed the containment, now i can drag the item over to whole page but i cannot drop it into the trash

Comment: Can you add your HTML and/or setup a jsbin.com example? I'm wondering if your "#Trash" div is inside the 'body' tag of your html. Also, is the "#Trash" div set to droppable?

Comment: The trash is droppable and it works on all items except this one

Comment: Which item isn't working. I started a jsbin https://jsbin.com/tufipon/edit?html,css,js,console,output and added the droppable code you didn't provide in your javascript. It appears to work. I'll add the droppable code to the answer above

Comment: I tried to drop the small height items and it works, but the big height items cannot be dropped.

Comment: What is the id it class of the "big" height item. I don't know which item is causing you trouble. Can you update the jsbin or give me more details

Answer (score -1):

actually i do many things to end this issue, but the solution was, change the size of the dragged item, so i added the following code to the draggable function:

> before update:

```
$('body .removable').draggable({
            cursor: 'move',
            helper:'clone'
            zIndex: 101,
            drag: function () {
                    $("#trash").removeClass("hidden");
                },
            stop: function () {
                    $("#trash").addClass("hidden");
                }
        });
```

> after update:

```
$('body .removable').draggable({
                cursor: 'move',
                helper: function (event) {
                    return $(event.currentTarget).clone().css({'width':'200px','height':'160px','overflow':'hidden'});
                },
                zIndex: 101,
                    drag: function () {
                        $("#trash").removeClass("hidden");
                    },
                    stop: function () {
                        $("#trash").addClass("hidden");
                    }
            });
```

Comment: You still have not provided any HTML that has the problem you claim to have solved. I have asked you which div ID or Class is the issue and you failed to answer. So this is not answering the question asked, but the issue in your private code which doesn't help the community.

Comment: I said in my question that my issue is in big size elements, and also I cannot add my html code because it’s dynamic code , this issue is not private and it’s very helpful for people, thanks for downvote

Comment: You can capture the HTML of dynamic code and post it as static. Big size elements without an actual size is not a definition.